# PhoneGap login Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I have made a  made a phonegap app  and i m confused when logging whether logging is success or even not succsess im getting the same error which handled in the else part.
Here is my Javascript Ajax login code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login").click(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var dataString = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&login=";
    if ($.trim(email).length > 0 & $.trim(password).length > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.43.173/viamobile/login.php",
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
          $("#login").html('Connecting...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == "success") {
            localStorage.login = "true";
            localStorage.email = email;
            window.location.href = "index.html";
          } else if (data = "failed") {
            alert("Login error");
            $("#login").html('Login');
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

and my PHP scripts

```html
<?php
include "db.php";
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $login = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"select * from `admin` where `username`='$email' and `password`='$password'"));
  if($login!=0)
  {
    echo "success";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "failed";
  }
}
?>


<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","phonegap");
?>
```

I actually need to validate the user and redirect to different page according to user access. But since this error I m unable to do so.Can some one show me where i went wrong?

Comment: **Don't trim the password** a space is a perfectly valid character as any other. I hate when i can't use any character that i want. What is wrong with having `∞` in your password for example? **You should also hash+salt the password** instead of storing it in plain text!

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you something like my working code. Client JS code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: /* GET or POST */,
  url: /* your url */,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json",
  beforeSend: function (event) {
    /* before funcs */
  }
})
.done(function (data) {
  if (data.status == "ok" || !data.error) {
    /* good */
  } else {
    /* manage error */
  }
})
.fail(function (data)  {
  /* manage error */
});
```